# Call an Action from an MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I'm trying to figure out how to call an action from an MVC view, not call a view URL.

I have an Action Method for signing off in the Account Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SignOff()
{
    authenticationService.SignOut();
    return View("SignOff");
}
```

And I'd like to call it from a cshtml page, like this:

```
<li>@Html.Action("SignOff","Account")</li>
```

The list is part of a drop down menu.

ActionLink doesn't work because I don't have an Account/SignOff page. The above code returns the following: "Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'." ActionLink just tells me the resource doesn't exist.

Is there anyway to do this? I just want users to be able to select a "Logout" item from a menu and then have the application call the SignOff method. Do I need to use Ajax? Javascript? I'm still experimenting. Thank yoU!

EDIT: Ok, it was the http.post that was keeping me from calling this directly. I got rid of the acceptverbs attribute and now I can call the method directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just redirect to the Login page or to any other public page (home page).

```
return RedirectToAction("Login");
```

Comment: Ok, so just create a page to link to and just have the page's controller redirect to the action. I'm guessing that means that there's no way to link directly to an Action from an HTML helper in a view. I'll give that a try and check back. Thank you!

Comment: As I said above, the httpverbs.post attribute was keeping me from accessing this method directly. Removing it removed my problem.